# When scraping the desired webpages, the content of all the .txt files are the nodes I selected

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm doing a basic web-scraping exercise for myself, extracting States of the Union from [this website](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/annual-messages-congress-the-state-the-union).

my code to get what I need looks like this.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(qdap)
library(dplyr)



#load webpage
pres.library <- read_html(x = "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/annual-messages-congress-the-state-the-union")

#get URL of links
links <- pres.library %>%
  html_nodes("span a , td~ td+ td a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

#get link text
text <- pres.library %>%
  html_nodes("span a , td~ td+ td a") %>%
  html_text()

#combine into df 
sotu <- data.frame (text = text, links = links, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

After cleaning, the dataframe looks like this for every State of the Union.

```
Year                                                                                                      links             President                 Party
1   2020 https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/address-before-joint-session-the-congress-the-state-the-union-27       Donald J. Trump            Republican
2   2019 https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/address-before-joint-session-the-congress-the-state-the-union-26       Donald J. Trump            Republican
3   2018 https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/address-before-joint-session-the-congress-the-state-the-union-25       Donald J. Trump            Republican
4   2017                                                    https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=123408       Donald J. Trump            Republican
5   2016                                                    https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111174          Barack Obama            Democratic
6   2015                                                    https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=108031          Barack Obama            Democratic
...
```

When I'm looping through my data-frame to extract the text using this

```
for (i in seq(nrow(sotu))) {
  sotu.text <- read_html(paste0(x = "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/annual-messages-congress-the-state-the-union"),sotu$links[i]) %>%
    html_nodes("span a , td~ td+ td a") %>%
    html_text()
  filename <- paste0("State of the Union", " ", sotu$Year[i], " ", sotu$President[i], " ", sotu$Party[i], ".txt")
  sink(file = filename) %>%
    cat(text) %>%
    sink()
}
```

The .txt files are in my directory but for some reason the content of all the .txt files are just the nodes I selected through the selectorgadget tool in Chrome.

I believe it has something to do with the "href" variable of html_attr?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Cleaning**

```
#combine into df 
sotu <- data.frame (text = text, links = links, stringsAsFactors = F)

#change text column to year
names(sotu)[1] <- "Year"

#remove redunant rows & row of 1973 sotu(nixon wrote 6 separate speeches with a different topic, will be added to 1973)
sotu <- sotu[-c(89, 87, 77, 52 ),]

#replace symbols
sotu$Year <- sub("‡", "", sotu$Year)

#replace Nixon 1973 speeches
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress: Overview and Goals", "1973", sotu$Year)
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress on Natural Resources and the Environment", "1973", sotu$Year)
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress on the Economy", "1973", sotu$Year)
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress on Human Resources", "1973", sotu$Year)
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress on Community Development", "1973", sotu$Year)
sotu$Year <- sub("State of the Union Message to the Congress on Law Enforcement and Drug Abuse Prevention", "1973", sotu$Year)

#order by year (no SOTU in 1933)
sotu <- arrange(sotu, desc(Year))

#add party and president name to the dataframe (watch out! because different parties are overlapping for the same year: 1953, 1961 & 1981) => add manually

#1 add order column
sotu$order <- c(1:246)

#2. Add name of presidents (probably a more productive way to do this, but haven't found it yet), William Harisson & James A. Garfield are ommited, no SOTU. Ad NA as starting value. 
sotu$President <- NA
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(246:239),
                         "George Washington", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(238:235),
                         "John Adams", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(234:227),
                         "Thomas Jefferson", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(226:219),
                         "James Madison", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(218:211),
                         "James Monroe", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(210:207),
                         "John Quincy Adams", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(206:199),
                         "Andrew Jackson", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(198:195),
                         "Martin Van Buren", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(194:191),
                         "John Tyler", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(190:187),
                         "James K. Polk", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(186),
                         "Zachary Taylor", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(185:183),
                         "Millard Fillmore", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(182:179),
                         "Franklin Pierce", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(178:175),
                         "James Buchanan", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(174:171),
                         "Abraham Lincoln", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(170:167),
                         "Andrew Johnson", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(166:159),
                         "Ulysses S. Grant", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(158:155),
                         "Rutherford B. Hayes", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(154:151),
                         "Chester A. Arthur", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(150:147),
                         "Grover Cleveland", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(146:143),
                         "Benjamin Harrison", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(142:139),
                         "Grover Cleveland", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(138:135),
                         "William McKinley", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(134:127),
                         "Theodore Roosevelt", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(126:123),
                         "William Howard Taft", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(122:115),
                         "Woodrow Wilson", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(114:113),
                         "Warren G. Harding", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(112:107),
                         "Calvin Coolidge", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(106:103),
                         "Herbert Hoover", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(102:90),
                         "Franklin D. Roosevelt", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(89:82),
                         "Harry S. Truman", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(81:72),
                         "Dwight D. Eisenhower", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(71:69),
                         "John F. Kennedy", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(68:63),
                         "Lyndon B. Johnson", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(62:51),
                         "Richard M. Nixon", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(50:48),
                         "Gerald R. Ford", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(47:41),
                         "Jimmy Carter", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(40:33),
                         "Ronald Reagan", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(32:29),
                         "George Bush", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(28:21),
                         "William J. Clinton", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(20:13),
                         "George W. Bush", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(12:5),
                         "Barack Obama", sotu$President)
sotu$President <- ifelse(sotu$order %in% c(4:1),
                         "Donald J. Trump", sotu$President)

#Add Political Party
sotu$Party <- NA

sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("George Washington"),
                     "Independent", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("John Adams"),
                     "Federalist", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("Thomas Jefferson", "James Madison", "James Monroe", "John Quincy Adams"),
                     "Democratic-Republican", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("Andrew Jackson", "Martin Van Buren", "James K. Polk", "Franklin Pierce", "James Buchanan", "Grover Cleveland", 
                                           "Woodrow Wilson", "Franklin D. Roosevelt", "Harry S. Truman", "John F. Kennedy", "Lyndon B. Johnson", "Jimmy Carter", 
                                           "William J. Clinton", "Barack Obama"),
                     "Democratic", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("John Tyler", "Zachary Taylor", "Millard Fillmore"),
                     "Whig", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("Andrew Johnson"),
                     "Democrat (Union)", sotu$Party)
sotu$Party <- ifelse(sotu$President %in% c("Abraham Lincoln", "Ulysses S. Grant", "Rutherford B. Hayes", "Chester A. Arthur", "Benjamin Harrison", 
                                           "William McKinley", "Theodore Roosevelt", "William Howard Taft", "Warren G. Harding", "Calvin Coolidge", "Herbert Hoover", 
                                           "Dwight D. Eisenhower", "Richard M. Nixon", "Gerald R. Ford", "Ronald Reagan", "George Bush", "George W. Bush", 
                                           "Donald J. Trump"),
                     "Republican", sotu$Party)

#order column is redundant, so it can be removed
sotu$order <- NULL

#rearrange the columns
select(sotu, "Year", "President", "Party", "links")
```

Comment: Can you include the cleaning part of the code so it is easier for us (or at least me) to replicate the problem?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I just added the cleaning part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be need something like

```
for (i in seq(nrow(sotu))) {
  sotu.text <- read_html(sotu$links[i]) %>%
    html_nodes(".col-sm-8") %>%
    html_text()
  filename <- paste0("State of the Union", " ", sotu$Year[i], " ", sotu$President[i], " ", sotu$Party[i], ".txt")
  cat(sotu.text, file=filename, sep = "\n")
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much again! 
May I ask where you found the correct node? (".col-sm-8"), and why is it different from the original ones?

Comment: Where did you find it in inspect elements? if you don't mind me asking, I did a search but I couldn't find it

Comment: you can googling it and find article like [this](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-inspect-and-change-style-using-google-chrome)